# Does leveldb have structural problems if values are blank and there's just a key?

Tags: leveldb

I'm working on a design where secondary indexes to data will be built with all the information in the key, needing nothing in the value side. Is this likely to cause problems?

I'm **not** asking is it *technically* possible to have a blank value. Are there any **structural consequences**, for example: adding sorted keys can unbalance some tree structures? (I'm not saying leveldb uses trees, just trying to think of an analogy ;-) )

ie: say a "primary record" looks like (nulls as separators)

- key = uniqueTableID \0 uniqueRowID
- value = some collection of fields

a secondary index to a typical single-valued field would look like:

- key = uniqueFieldID \0 keyValue \0 uniqueRowID

that allows iteration by the partial key [uniqueFieldID \0 keyValue] and it also makes it easy to find these keys and delete them if the main record is deleted or key value changes, working back from the main record's uniqueRowID. So there might be several key values ending in the same uniqueRowID but can only ever be one key for the particular combination starting with a uniqueFieldID  and ending with a uniqueRowID

The only thing is that I don't have any need to put a value in the value side of the pair.

I'm pretty happy with this conceptual design, just checking to see if anyone can spot holes in it. For example, if it would distort leveldb internals causing performance issues.

I expect there would be tens of thousands of such keys in one particular app.

As an example of a value we *might* want to store, a secondary word index to a text field mightlook like:

- key = uniqueFieldID \0 keyValue \0 GUID
- value = count of word occurrences or maybe a list of offsets if scanning large blobs was expensive

Comment: I'm curious how you clean up stale secondary index entries when a primary record changes or is deleted.  Do you always fetch the existing record before an update or delete?

Comment: Wait and read the book (just kidding). No I compare values before deciding if I need to update secondary indexes on an update. Obviously they need updating on most deletes (I check to see if the optional secondary key should be there based on "record" values).

Comment: What book (I'm very interested)?  To compare the values though do you first fetch the old record?  Even on a delete it seems like you need to know the field/value pairs so that you can delete the corresponding index entries.

Comment: Getting Started with LevelDB coming soon from Packt. There are actually a range of different approaches you can take as to how you store records, possibilities multiply the more you try to write a tight description of them (exasperated sigh). For example, say you are storing an entire "record" in one main value with the "primary key" as its key. If you are currently editing that record in a GUI you have it loaded as the current record so don't need to read prior to deleting. However, if you're doing a mass delete then yes you need to read records to get secondary keys to delete.

Comment: Definitely going to check out the book.  Don't you loose atomicity when the record is read first?

Comment: Remember that LevelDB is being used, in this context, as a single-user database. Yes it's a good point that atomicity is lost but the most likely consequence is attempting to delete a secondary key which is no longer there, so it is a safe fail. If you're using this approach as the backend to a shared database then I'd have to think about it more but I suspect it is still pretty safe.

Comment: Yeah, I was imagining this in the context of multiple threads reading and writing to the database.  I suppose if all the write requests are serialized to a single writer thread then there might not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys and values in LevelDB are opaque arrays and a quick look into the documentation for [constructor of a Slice](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/source/browse/include/leveldb/slice.h) shows how you can create an empty slice:

```
// Create an empty slice.
Slice() : data_(""), size_(0)
```

This is useful exactly for the type of situations where you don't have any value data.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't asking if it was technically feasible so much as does this cause problems with the data storage, will try to add details to the question to clarify.

Comment: We haven't seen any problem so far and we have millions of entries with no values in our database. Furthermore, all the storage is key-based and the value is ignored for the most part. The only "significant" time when the LevelDB considers the value is when it runs out of space in a particular bucket (because the values are taking too much space). If anything, having empty values will perform much faster with a large database since the LevelDB can fit more keys in a single file, thus it manage less files.

Comment: Ticked because of the answer in the comment above!

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine since even leveldb stores deletes as keys without values. Internally leveldb uses and prefix length encoding for keys in each SST which would help further in reducing the key sizes for your particular case. The only skewness in you case would be in the index sizes. Typically the index size would be a small fraction of the data blocks (assuming small keys and relatively big values), while in your case the index could be relatively big, since index stores a key per data block.